# UnicodeFont rendering seems to block everything else from rendering?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

After over two hours (Yes, a flippin' long time!) of attempting to debug this code, I appear to have a line rendering text which seems to be blotting out everything else behind it (or something).

The text I am attempting to draw on that method works fine, however for whatever reason, there seems to be nothing else rendering.

I did two experiments with `if (true) return;` lines.

The first experiment looked like this:

```
 public static void render() {
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrix(orthographicProjectionMatrix);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    width = Display.getWidth()/2;
    height = Display.getHeight()/2;
    int ch = Display.getHeight()/10;
   // int locationY = 100;
    //if (true) return;
    //if (true) return;



        String msg = loadMessage;

        if (msg.contains("RED")){
            msg = msg.replace("RED", "");
            int offset = font.getWidth(msg)/2;
            font.drawString(Display.getWidth()/2 - offset, Display.getHeight()/2, msg, Color.red);
            if (true) return;
        }else if (msg.contains("YELLOW")){
            msg = msg.replace("YELLOW", "");
            int offset = font.getWidth(msg)/2;
            font.drawString(Display.getWidth()/2 - offset, Display.getHeight()/2, msg, Color.yellow);
            if (true) return;
        }else{
            int offset = font.getWidth(msg)/2;
         font.drawString(Display.getWidth()/2 - offset, Display.getHeight()/2, msg, Color.magenta);
         if (true) return;
        }


    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrix(perspectiveProjectionMatrix);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}
```

And the second one was like this:

```
    public static void render() {
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrix(orthographicProjectionMatrix);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    width = Display.getWidth()/2;
    height = Display.getHeight()/2;
    int ch = Display.getHeight()/10;
   // int locationY = 100;
    //if (true) return;
    //if (true) return;



        String msg = loadMessage;

        if (msg.contains("RED")){
            msg = msg.replace("RED", "");
            int offset = font.getWidth(msg)/2;
            if (true) return;
            font.drawString(Display.getWidth()/2 - offset, Display.getHeight()/2, msg, Color.red);
        }else if (msg.contains("YELLOW")){
            msg = msg.replace("YELLOW", "");
            int offset = font.getWidth(msg)/2;
            if (true) return;
            font.drawString(Display.getWidth()/2 - offset, Display.getHeight()/2, msg, Color.yellow);

        }else{
            int offset = font.getWidth(msg)/2;
          if (true) return;
         font.drawString(Display.getWidth()/2 - offset, Display.getHeight()/2, msg, Color.magenta);

        }


    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrix(perspectiveProjectionMatrix);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}
```

With the first one, nothing rendered (Edit: Text now renders, however still just blue behind it).

With the second one, everything except the text that this particular method is rendering worked perfectly.

So, what is the difference? I just can't fathom it. And I just can't fix it.

Result of test 1:
[image]
Result of test 2:
[image]

Other relevant code:

```
static void setUpFonts() {
    java.awt.Font awtFont = new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 18);
    font = new UnicodeFont(awtFont);
    font.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect(java.awt.Color.white));
    font.addAsciiGlyphs();
    try {
        font.loadGlyphs();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Calling the method:

```
ready2D();
    TextDemo.setUpCamera();
    TextDemo.render();
    camSetup();
    ready3D();
```

Calling the method variation (Suggested in comments) which had no difference whatsoever:

```
    ready2D();
    glPushMatrix();
    TextDemo.setUpCamera();
    TextDemo.render();
    glPopMatrix();
    ready3D();
```

Readying 2D:

```
static void ready2D()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLU.gluOrtho2D(0.0f, 1, 1, 0.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.375f, 0.375f, 0.0f);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Ready 3D:

```
static void ready3D()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(45, (float) Display.getWidth()/Display.getHeight(), 0.1f, 5000.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Ready2D and Ready3D are known to work, as I use them further down in the code to implement the health bar in one of the above screenshots with no issues.

Please tell me if any more information is required. I hope I have put enough.

Comment: What is `TerrainDemo.reg`?

Comment: Well `if(true) return; if(TerrainDemo.reg)` always returns, but `if(TerrainDemo.reg) {if(true) return;` won't return if `TerrainDemo.reg` is false. The problem is in the stuff after the `if` statement, which is skipped when the function returns early.

Comment: @immibis Oh!! Dammit! Give me a second to clean up my code and then I will look into what line is actually causing the issue.

Eh, and how I didnt notice that I don't know. I must be an idiot.

Comment: @immibis Just what I thought. I made an answer and saw your comment immediately after being done :(

Comment: Problem line of code is 'font.drawString(Display.getWidth()/2 - offset, Display.getHeight()/2, msg, Color.magenta);' - Editing the post...

Comment: What does drawstring do? Codewise I mean.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper I am using the UnicodeFont class from Slick:
http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/UnicodeFont.html

Comment: Slick is 2D. Are you sure it doesn't mess up your matrices? For testing push them before the draw call and afterwards pop them back.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper Updated the original post again.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I meant the drawString and both matrices.

Comment: Issue still not resolved.

@Dawnkeeper I can't due to using Push/Pop matrix calls elsewhere. I can only push and pop matrixes once, its not as if I can store the pushed matrix to a variable and then pop back from that variable, unfortunatley.

Comment: Push/Pop can be used multiple times. See [here](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

```
if (TerrainDemo.reg){
  if (true) return;
```

and

```
static boolean reg = false;
```

Since TerrainDemo.reg is false, the statement `if (true) return` isn't executed (unless you change the value of TerrainDemo.reg, obviously).

Since your code works if the method `render()` returns almost immediately, then there must be an error in the OpenGL calls of said method that prevents the rest of the scene from rendering correctly, not a logical error. Use [`glGetError()`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Error) to identify the error.

Comment: return; throws an error in my IDE. if (true) return; does not.

I will look into your GLGetError thing.

Comment: Your IDE is weird. About glGetError, include GLUT and use gluErrorString(): `gluErrorString(glGetError())`

Comment: His IDE just detects unreachable code. That's not weird.

Comment: @filsmick I used System.out.println(glGetError()) and it returned a 0 every time, which I presume means there is no error?

Comment: Yes. The problem is probably not throwing an OpenGL error, and is more subtle. I can't help you on that - I was just reading your question and noticed the obvious.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper Still, this should **not** throw an error, rather issue a warning. And it should also point out the rest of the code, that is unreachable too.

Comment: The point of `if(true) return;` is that in Java it's illegal to have code following a `return` in the same block.

Comment: @immibis Uh, that's strange. I thought it would just issue a warning. But it makes sense too, since it is useless to have code that is never executed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @filsmick IMO it's a bad decision to make it an error, precisely because of situations like this. A warning is fine.

Comment: Almost got it fixed by using glPushAttrib() and glPopAttrib().

Comment: I DID IT!! I fixed it!

Posting an answer to my own question soon.

Answer (score 2):

The following calls:

```
glLoadIdentity();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrix(orthographicProjectionMatrix);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

Appeared to be affecting my drawing matrices for 3D.

To fix this, I used something that I had never used before, `glPushAttrib()` and `glPopAttrib()`.

The following code fixed the issue:

```
glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrix(orthographicProjectionMatrix);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    width = Display.getWidth()/2;
    height = Display.getHeight()/2;
    int ch = Display.getHeight()/10;
   // int locationY = 100;
    //if (true) return;
    //if (true) return;

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        String msg = loadMessage;

        if (false){ //If statements are here, but are irrelevant to fixing the issue
        }else{
            int offset = font.getWidth(msg)/2;
         font.drawString(Display.getWidth()/2 - offset, Display.getHeight()/2, msg, Color.magenta);
         glPopMatrix();
         glPopAttrib();
         System.out.println("Error: " + glGetError());
         glGetError();
         if (true) return;
        }
```

Thank you all who helped me debug my issue! Your help was invaluable.

Comment: Oh great, I can only self-accept my answer in 10 hours after posting this. Great community, but the system itself is pretty terrible in cases like this.